# Как создать схему базы данных которая имеет сущность с различными дополнительными свойствами?

Tags: база-данных

Имеется пользователь user, который может быть либо физическим (natural), либо юридическим (legal) лицом. На сколько правильно создавать схему следующего вида:

*запросы будут с join и сразу оба типа персон, и по раздельности*

```
user
----
id int
person string (legal|natural)

person_legal
----
id int
user_id int
prop_1
...

person_natural
----
id int
user_id int
prop_2
...
```

или:

```
user
----
id int
person string (legal|natural)

user_props
-------
id int
user_id
prop
value
```

Comment: Я бы первый вариант выбрал. только просто id в подчиненных таблицах не делал. В качестве первичного ключа задал бы тот же самый id, что в первой таблице, который вы видимо в user_id превратили. Была бы связь один-к-одному. Вторая схема это классический EAV, он конечно замечательный при поиске по произвольным реквизитам, но вот просто список пользователей с параметрами получить - дико тормозной.

Comment: И конечно надо смотреть какая СУБД используется, например в postgesql для решения этой задачи просто напрашивается наследование таблиц

Comment: Да, используется именно postgresql. С id я действительно перебрал. За наследование отдельное спасибо))).

Comment: Mike, если мне нужно выбрать оба типа одним запросом, при этом используется inner, в этом случае использовать IF?

Comment: нет. inner все сломает. он всегда должен присоединить какую нибудь запись. так что два left join и можно просто с условием a.id=b.id даже тип не проверять, если запись приклеилась, значит тип тот :)

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог.